# The history list in my firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

```
history.length
1
```

Number 1 displayed on my firefox console,why so many web urls when to click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>?

[image]
How to list all the historical urls with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`history` exposes the *session history* of the *current tab/window*. I.e., anything you can get back to using the back button in the upper left.

That is not your *entire* browser history ever visited, which you see when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

No, the Javascript API doesn't expose a complete history of everything ever, as a simple security measure.